# how to pass firstview value according to row selected of tableview in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, uiviewcontroller

I have 3 `ViewController`, my `FirstView` is where I am showing all data which is fetched from database and in `SecondView` I am inserting new data in database.
Up to here is working good

My problem when I click on **Edit** button then my `FirstView` goes to edit mode.
At this time, I have to pass all values which are displayed on `FirstView`.

If I select any row then it goes to my `ThirdView` which is my Update view, where i can change values if needed. In my `ThirdView` I have UITableView, I want same value to be displayed which are in FirstView

How to do this please help me on this.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the `dataSource` for the `ThirdView`'s table view  to the `FirstView`. For this you need to send the reference of the `FirstView` to `ThirdView`.

```
tableView.dataSource = firstViewRefernce;
```